# How to go to a line based on number of words on a line?

Tags: search

Just like the title says. How do I identify (and goto) a line based on its word count? For example, what if I want to go to the next line containing more than 5 words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions to match lines containing at least four words (sequences of at least one non-blank character) followed by spaces (sequences of at least one blank character), plus a fifth non-blank character indicating the fifth word.

You can use [`\S`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CS) and [`\s`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cs) to match non-blanks and blanks. You can use [`\{4}`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%7B) to match 4 of a pattern. And [`\+`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F+) to match the repeats of non-blanks and blanks.

I recommend using ["very magic"](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv) regular expressions, which will save you from having to type (even more) backslashes!

To match *exactly* 5 words on a line:

```
/\v^\s*(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$
```

Matches optional whitespace, followed by 4 repetitions of a word with spaces after it, followed by a fifth word, optional whitespace and the end of the line.

To match *at least* 5 words on a line:

```
/\v(\S+\s+){4}\S
```

You can make use of a substring match in that case. As long as you're seeing the 4 sets of spaces in between words, you know there are at least 5 words.

If you want to use a different definition of a word (for example, sequences of [`\w`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cw) or [`\k`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Ck) characters) then use the corresponding opposite (`\W` or `\K`) for the separators in between the words.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks for your help!